# Photoshop: Incorrect placement of new grid

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

I'm trying to create a new guide line in Photoshop CC (2017).

I've changed my 0,0 point in the file to be at the corner of a particular layer (so no longer at 0,0--or the upper left of the image).

When I click "new guide" and put in a value (like 3 in), the new guide will appear as if I had never moved the 0,0 point.  It will show the guide if I kept the 0,0 point at the default upper left hand corner of the file.

I've never run into this problem before.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The grid and origin are not linked with the placement of guides. What I suggest you do is use the grid feature in Photoshop which **is** linked to the placement of the origin. You can then snap guides to the grid if you want, then hide the grid perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I *don't know* if it is by design or an error. Photoshop CC2017/Mac here.

The `New Guide` ***menu*** item *always* uses the canvas or artboard boundaries at 0,0.

The `New Guide` ***command*** does not care, or read, where the origin for guides may have been moved to in any instance.

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I think it's failure on the software.